# Why isn't this knockout code picking up changes bound to an ObservableArray?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've got some strange behavior in (what should be) some relatively straight forward code. I'm trying to prepend an `<input>` tag onto a list of elements.

**HTML**

```
<button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
<div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <input data-bind="value: $parent.items()[$index()]" />
    <button data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Remove</button>
    <br>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function ItemViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        self.items = ko.observableArray();

        self.addItem = function() {
            self.items.unshift('');
        }

        self.removeItem = function(name) {
            self.items.remove(name);
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ItemViewModel());
```

**What's going wrong:**

`RemoveItem` is sending an empty string to the function rather than the contents of the `input` element. However, what's weird is that this only applies to the most recently appended item AND only if no other item has been clicked. For instance, if I have on `input` type some text, and click `remove`, an empty string is sent to my function. However, if I add another `input` element via the `add` button, Knockout seems to 'reflow' and the original field picks up the changes in the text field and can be removed without a problem.

I'm pretty baffled here. Why isn't Knockout picking up the changes on recently prepended items?

Comment: `<input data-bind="value: $parent.items()[$index()]" />` seems weird... is there a reason you dont use `data-bind="value: $data"`?  no idea if this is at all related to your problem

Comment: The other thing is that the `<br>` will need to be closed e.g. `<br />` .  Knockoutjs doesn't like unclosed tags generally.

Comment: @NathanFisher: `<br>` is a void element, it doesn't need to be "closed".

Comment: so it should be fixed in knockout 3.0 according to https://github.com/knockout/knockout/issues/708 by using `$rawData`, but i am unable to see it working in a jsfiddle...

Comment: can tell I havent been at this in a while... so observablearrays are great at tracking what they contain, but they dont necessarily mean that their contents are observable.  I think this is a case of the model data needed to be updated

Comment: @JeffMercado I agree that it doesn't need to be closed in standard HTML.  It's just that I have had issues with knockoutjs (in the past) not rendering correctly with elements that are not required to be "closed".  Closing them anyway usually fixed any issues I had.

Answer (score 3):

So binding directly to a string doesnt provide the two way binding you would expect, regardless of if you had the value in an observableArray.  observableArrays just track changes to a collection (items being added/removed) but not changes to individual items in the array.

To fix this problem, you will need to update your data model a bit:

js

```
self.addItem = function() {
    self.items.unshift({name: ko.observable('')});
}
```

html

```
<input data-bind="value: name" />
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e2b0089j/